# Image in html has been preprocessed?

Tags: html, image

I am displaying the images with different size in html using img tag. One of the image is 267x168 while the other is 1068x672. Both of images are same but different size. Suppose the smaller image will be aliased as it has been displayed in 50% width. But both of them just look the same. Are the images has been proprocessed before displaying? If yes, how to disable it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Result Comparison</h1>

        <style>
            img { 
                width:100%; 
            }

            td{
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding:1%;
            }
        </style>

        <table style="width:100%">  
            <col width="50%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><a href="original.png"><img src="original.png" width=50%/></a>Original (size)</td>
                <td align ="center"><a href="bicubic.png"><img src="bicubic.png"/></a>Bicubic (size)</td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><a href="average.png"><img src="average.png"/></a>Average (size)</td>
                <td align ="center"><a href="median.png"><img src="median.png"/></a>Median (size)</td>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: How can we know, if you don't show the code. It looks like inheriting styles from parent.

Comment: @Berkay Code added. Sorry about that.

Comment: Give us a screenshot maybe? It sounds like you want to know why two different-sized images look the same when displayed at the same size.

Comment: @Clonkex The original one is 267x168 while bicubic one is 1068x672

Comment: I think I know what you're saying, but I couldn't find any information, so I [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158654/what-image-filter-is-used-when-resizing-images-with-css). There's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering) in one of the comments that could possibly be of use to you.

Comment: @Clonkex Thank for your info. So it seem like some processing must be done to zoom in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you resize an image, some processing must happen. The software doing the resizing (be that an image-editing program or a browser) must work out some way to remove pixels or add them. It does this using an *image filter* algorithm. Some common ones are point, linear/bilinear and cubic/bicubic.

In most image editing programs you can choose which type of filter to use, but browsers decide for you. Luckily it looks like you can have *some* control; based on the information on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering), it looks like you could add a CSS rule to get a pixelated look, like so:

```css
img {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

***However***, it's worth noting that to get the pixelated look you have to use a different rule for certain browsers, according to [this page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-crisp-edges). In Chrome, `pixelated` works, but not `crisp-edges`. It's the opposite for Firefox.