# What image filter is used when resizing images with CSS?

Tags: html, css

If I do this:

```css
#image {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg">
```

...what image filter (i.e. point, linear, bicubic, etc.) is used by the browser to resize the images? Is it different for each browser? Is this something we have control of?

Comment: slightly outdated but on-topic http://entropymine.com/resamplescope/notes/browsers/

Comment: @Ihazkode Interesting, thanks for the link. I'd like to see if there's a more up-to-date reference though.

Comment: Finally, a real question is SO!

Comment: This mdn entry lists some default values, e.g. "Since version 1.9 (Firefox 3.0), Gecko uses bilinear resampling (high quality)." https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering

Comment: @Prinzhorn That's also pretty interesting. It looks like it's at least partially supported across most platforms: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-crisp-edges